# How to modify contents of a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list which contains the following items:

```
my_data_list = ['1.7.45.67.3', '\'$10$This is the first team in the league\', "$12$b\'This team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid\'"']
```

I want to be able to convert the contents of the list after the first index to be something as the following. The list could have several items after the first index and it would be just a couple of more `{}` for each of them.;

```
my_final_result = ['1.7.45.67.3', '{{10, This is the first team in the league}, {12, This team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid}}']
```

I am really confused on how to efficiently do it. I am very new to python and would appreciate any help to solve this efficiently.

Comment: How did you get those strings with the symbols in them?

Comment: This is strings I received from a udp package. I am only interested in the integer fields in the dollar sign and the string associated with it.

Comment: Can you give some context as to what these characters stand for? Getting the integers is doable since they're isolated by dollar signs. However, i don't know why the remaining text parts are different. The one beside `10` is just a simple string but the other one is enclosed by quotes and has a `b` outside.

Comment: That b' is because it is encoded string and sone strings are not encoded.  I am not intrested in those special characters.  I can ignore those characters such as b' and / or \ and focus on actual characters . Hope it makes it clear. Only the dollars sign separate string of interest for me. Please do keep me posted. Thank you so much for the help. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution**

```
def convert_data_list(data_list):
    data_list = [s.translate({ord(c): None for c in '\'\"'}) for s in data_list]
    result = []
    for data in data_list:
        pairs = []
        for int_text_string in data.split(','):
            integer, text = [d for d in int_text_string.split('$') if d.strip() != '']
            text = text.lstrip('b')
            pairs.append('{' + integer + ', ' + text + '}')
        result.append('{' + ', '.join(pairs) + '}')
    return result
```

Sample Usage

```
my_data_list = [
    '1.7.45.67.3', 
    '\'$10$This is the first team in the league\', "$12$b\'This team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid\'"',
    '\'$114$Sample data\', "$78$b\'Hello world\'", "$48$b\'A third pair\'"',
    ]
my_final_result = convert_data_list(my_data_list[1:])    # do not include zeroth index
my_final_result = [my_data_list[0]] + my_final_result    # add zeroth index back
print(result)
```

Output

```
['1.7.45.67.3', '{{10, This is the first team in the league}, {12, This team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid}}', '{{114, Sample data}, {78, Hello world}, {48, A third pair}}']
```

---

**Explanation**

This function accepts a list of strings. Only pass in the strings after the 1st index.

```
def convert_data_list(data_list):
```

**1. Remove all single & double quotes**

```
data_list = [s.translate({ord(c): None for c in '\'\"'}) for s in data_list]
```

So this sample string

```
'\'$10$This is the first team in the league\', "$12$b\'This team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid\'"'
```

becomes

```
'$10$This is the first team in the league, $12$bThis team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid'
```

*There are other ways to do this in python*

**2. Loop through each string**

```
result = []
for data in data_list:
```

The temporary result is stored in `result`

**3. Split each string by the comma then loop through each**

```
pairs = []
for int_text_string in data.split(','):
```

From step 1,

```
'$10$This is the first team in the league, $12$bThis team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid'
```

becomes a list of strings

```
['$10$This is the first team in the league', ' $12$bThis team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid']
```

**4. Extract the integer and text values**

```
integer, text = [d for d in int_text_string.split('$') if d.strip() != '']
```

Given `' $12$bThis team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid'`, splitting by `'$'` gives:

```
[' ', '12', 'bThis team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid']
```

Since there may be strings which only contain whitespaces, don't include it in the list giving a final result:

```
['12', 'bThis team is at location 132.45.67 on the grid']
```

So the 0-index is the integer and the 1-index is the text. It is then assigned to variables `integer` and `text` by list unpacking.

**5. Remove the first character 'b' from the left**

```
text = text.lstrip('b')
```

This does nothing if the string doesn't start with a `'b'`

**6. Format the result**

```
        pairs.append('{' + integer + ', ' + text + '}')
    result.append('{' + ', '.join(pairs) + '}')
return result
```

---

I can't say anything about how efficient this is, but it does work.

Comment: I will have a look into it qnd let you know. Thank you so much it means alot to me. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I am currently looking into the solution. I might have some questions. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what the ``` result ``` is in the ```my_final_result = [my_data_list[0]] + result ```. Did you mean ```my_final_result = [my_data_list[0]] + my_final_result ``` ?

Comment: @Anna I edited the `result` type. Sorry about that.

Comment: Regarding seeing individual characters, you might be passing a raw string instead of a list of string/s. Maybe you used `my_data_list[1]` instead of `my_data_list[1:]`.